# Country specific page-rank

Tags: google-api, pagerank, google-ranking

Google PageRank API allows you to get a pagerank of a domain name, I assume it is for all registered domains globally. Say I want to get a pagerank amongst Italian or say Spanish websites. Is there a way I can use Google feature to have a list of pagerank amongst specific TLDs?

I understand its difficultly without available API as having all the domain list of all valid TLD and doing some slow math to compare global rank with TLD rank and I don't think it is a solution at all.

So my questions are:
1. Is there an API way to compute pagerank amongst specific TLD / country specific domains
2. If not, which way to go? Do a math or? Give your recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with google but you can use alexa.com [API](http://aws.amazon.com/awis/)

You can easily get ranks by country then:

http://www.alexa.com/topsites/category/Top/World

Comment: Everyone knows that Alexa's service is erratic and crap. They cannot have any real idea of how much traffic you have, unless you pay for the premium service, which is inferior to Google's free service anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab PR via tools like http://seotoolsforexcel.com PR will disapear in 2016!